# Wordpress, bbPress and iOS scheme URL

Tags: ios, wordpress, url-scheme, bbpress

I'm currently developing an iOS app along with a Wordpress site with the bbPress plugin.

I would like to allow any user to easily post links with custom schemes in the forum like :

`myappname://badebidobudy/fdjlkqsfj`

I saw that in bbPress an admin can indeed post a link like this :

`<a href="myappname://badebidobudy/fdjlkqsfj">Da link</a>`

and bbPress tells me why :

> Your account has the ability to post unrestricted HTML content.

But when an anonymous user wants to do this, the custom scheme is removed and the resulting html code is :

`<a href="//badebidobudy/fdjlkqsfj">Da link</a>`

So my question is : how can I configure (or tweak) Wordpress to at least accept my url scheme or even recognize a raw link with a custom scheme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments of : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/

I ended implementing a small plugin, here is its php code (the protocol I add is "newzik") :

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: NZK links support
* Plugin URI: http://newzik.com/
* Description: Adds support to newzik:// links
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Pierre Mardon
* Author URI: http://newzik.com/
* License: None
*/



/**
 * Extend list of allowed protocols.
 *
 * @param array $protocols List of default protocols allowed by WordPress.
 *
 * @return array $protocols Updated list including new protocols.
 */
function wporg_extend_allowed_protocols( $protocols ){
    $protocols[] = 'newzik';
    return $protocols;
}
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols' , 'wporg_extend_allowed_protocols' );
?>
```